# How is the helicity fixed by little group scaling?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, scattering, lorentz-symmetry

When reading about [Scattering Amplitudes Notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697), the text said the following:

*Under little group scaling of each particle $i = 1, 2, . . . , n$ , the on-shell amplitude transforms homogeneously with weight $−2h_i$, where $h_i$ is the helicity of particle $i$:*

$$A_n( \{ |1\rangle  |1], h_1\}, . . . , \{t_i |i\rangle, t^{−1}_i|i], h_i\}, ...) = t^{−2h_i}_i A_n(... \{|i\rangle, |i], h_i\} . . .)\tag{2.93}$$

*An on-shell 3-points amplitude $A$ (...) Let us suppose that it depends on angle brackets only.*

*We can then write a general Ansatz:*

$$A_3(1^{h_1}2^{h_2}3^{h_3})= c \langle 12 \rangle ^{x_{12}} \langle 13 \rangle ^{x_{13}} \langle 23 \rangle ^{x_{23}}\tag{2.94} $$

*The little group scaling (first equation above) fixes:*

$$-2h_1 =x_{12}+x_{13},$$
$$-2h_2 =x_{12}+x_{23},$$
$$-2h_3 =x_{13}+x_{23}. \tag{2.95}$$

**I don't understand how the first equation was used to obtain these last 3 equalities.**
**How can this be used to calculate the MHV of particles?**

Answer (score 1):

In eq. (2.10) of [Elvang and Huang](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697) it is explained that square/angle spinors has [helicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity) $\pm 1/2$, respectively. (If the particle 3-momentum is along the $z$-axis, then the generator of the helicity/little group-scaling is given by $\sigma_z$.) This leads to the scaling $t^{\mp 1}$ for the square/angle spinors, respectively, cf. eq. (2.92).

Using eq. (2.92) on the RHS and eq. (2.93) on the LHS of the Ansatz (2.94) yields the sought-for eq. (2.95).

Comment: I understand that those equations are all used, but I don't see how (eq(2.95))  are obtained.

(2.94) is of the same form as (2.93).
And I believe the rhs of (2.93) is obtained from (2.92).
But I still don't get how we can go from these to (2.95)

Comment: I updated the answer.